# How to pass javascript value to cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

i'm trying to pass javascript value to cookie, but code passes only [object HTMLInputElement] value to cookie, what i'm doing wrong?

```
var M=document.getElementById('a');

//   counts <span> elements
var N=M.getElementsByTagName('Span');

var largo = N.length;


var myData = Array();
for (var i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
    myData[i]=N[i].innerHTML;
}


function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}
return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
setCookie("chords", myDATA, 365);
}
```

this code gets all the chords from  elements and I need to store all those chords into cookie

Comment: What is "N" ?? And where are you calling these cookies functions..??

Comment: issue with myData Object. please check it has the correct value or not. also tell us what is N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to show the span elements value in the cookie, instead of `[object HTMLSpanElement]`

So if you check my fiddle, it will show that it returns the value of the span elements inside the cookie.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aox53dbn/3/)

```
function checkCookie() 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < N.length; i++) 
    {
        myData[i] = N[i].innerHTML;
    }

    if (getCookie("chords"))
    {
        console.log(" COOKIE EXISTS ");
    }
    else
    {
       console.log(" COOKIE DOESN'T EXISTS ");
       setCookie("chords", myData, 365);  
    }
}
```

Comment: If this isn't as quite as what you wanted, please comment and explain.